Cannot access 'androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase' which is a supertype of 'net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase'
I am trying to use SQLite and sqlcipher for my Android project but when I run , I get the following error, can someone help me to understand what the issue is and how to fix this?
Cannot access 'androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase' which is a supertype of 'net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Project uses:
androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.2.0
net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.5.4
Trying to update sqlite to latest dependency but still same error
androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.4.0

You need to add the androidx.sqlite dependency, like this:
implementation "net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.5.3"
implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.2.0'

It should solve the issue.
